# Ubuntu VM Failed Package Upgrade due to No space left on device: Troubleshoot for Root Cause and Solutions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, openstack

After a failed attempt to upgrade MySQL server on a Ubuntu VM, it seems to have ate up any remaining partition space

```
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################|

done!
sed: couldn't flush stdout: No space left on device
dpkg: error processing package mecab-ipadic-utf8 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to fill /var/lib/dpkg/updates/tmp.i with padding: No space left on device
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

diagnostics:

```
(base) ubuntu@db-server-2:~$ sudo du -sh /
du: cannot access '/proc/22686/task/22686/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/22686/task/22686/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/22686/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/22686/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
2.9G    /
(base) ubuntu@db-server-2:~$ sudo df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           799M  8.6M  790M   2% /run
/dev/vda1       2.9G  2.9G     0 100% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           799M     0  799M   0% /run/user/1000
(base) ubuntu@db-server-2:~$ sudo df -i /
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vda1      384000 152311 231689   40% /
```

It looks like /dev/vda1 is full.

I'm a Linux newbie, got a couple of questions here:

1. How to free up space? Do I go to root directory and du -hs each directories? If so, what am I looking for?
2. Why is the vda1 partition so small when I have allocated 80G of virtual disk space to the VM? If it's an issue how can I increase its size?

Thanks in advance!

[Specs on Openstack VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oER2U.png)

Comment: Perhaps the filesystem was created before you enlarged the disk, in such case it's not yet aware of the unclaimed size. You should run `fdisk -l /dev/vda` and [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1508701/edit) the question to report the result.

Comment: @A.B Thanks found the problem. It's with my Openstack instance setup

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue to be a Openstack noob error

I set up my VM with the following Flavor thinking the 'size' attribute was my disk capacity 
[Flavor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VXi7.png)

It turns out that the volume that is attached to the instance holds the disk volume for the VM

[volumes attached to instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFV0O.png)

Thanks to @A.B for the hint